# Having trouble with Ruby(rails) timestamp and jQuery timeago plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I am passing an object back from my rails app with a timestamp. I'm trying to use jQuery to take the format it comes in and parse it to something like "5 minutes ago" "an hour ago" etc.

```
$.each(data, function(i, issue){
          var created =  $.timeago(issue.created_at.to_datetime);
          ...
```

When I trigger the event that causes this, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
} has no method 'timeago'
```

Is there a way to do this with the timeago plugin or should I perhaps try a different method?

Comment: Did you include the timeago plugin before trying to use it, and what exactly is `issue.created_at.to_datetime`

Comment: Curious as to how are you able to use `.to_datetime` on `issue.created_at` Is issue a JSON object?

Comment: The timeago plugin is included and loading correctly on the page.
Issue is a JSON object I passed from my rails controller.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a rails built-in method?

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(issue.created_at) %>
```

Comment: I am reconstructing a list with AJAX by clearing it and then reconstructing the format by sending the info back to the JS as JSON. So I'm trying to reconstruct the date/time as words on the JS side.